# How to get darker fire when the environment is dynamic sky

Tags: materials, fire

[image]

[image: These are my shaders..]

I am trying to make the flamethrower of charizard(pokemon) like in Anime style but since I am new to blender I can't create a good fire but this is the fire I created.

Well the fire is fine but the problem is it is very light and because of dynamic sky it get even more lighter.What shades I should use to make my fire more darker and anime-style???

Comment: perhaps *Volume to Mesh* modifier would be more appropriate, depending on what you want

Comment: https://youtu.be/P0mTewFohUo ... BTW it is always better to add reference image of desired result (your goal how fire should looks like)